# MySql How to get records as per request in the table mentioned

Tags: mysql

This is am employees record. Say some employees are manager to other employees and recognized by `emp_id` in `manager_id` column.
For example Manager of Ram and Laxhman is Gopi, Manager of Krishna is Laxhman.
Now i want to get records of emp_id, emp_name and his manager name.
Below is the table

```
emp_id  emp_name    manager_id
1       gopi            0
2       Ram             1
3       Laxhman         1
4       krishna         3
```

Would anybody help me in sorting this query using mysql(in single query).

Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like an INNER JOIN (google if needed)

Comment: assuming table name as emp_tab i tried this. but unable to work "select emp_id, emp_name, manager_id, (select emp_name from emp_tab where manager_id=emp_id) as manager_name from emp_tab". please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to LEFT JOIN the emp_tab table to itself:

```
SELECT emp_tab.emp_id, emp_tab.emp_name, man_tab.emp_name AS man_name
FROM emp_tab AS emp_tab
LEFT JOIN emp_tab AS man_tab ON emp_tab.manager_id=man_tab.emp_id
```

The LEFT JOIN results in you getting each record from the first ("left") emp_tab table (referenced as `emp_tab`) and then one match, if it exists, to the second emp_tab table referenced as `man_tab`.

Note that `man_tab` is an alias for the emp_tab itself, but it is used to extract the information for managers only. If we did not "alias" the table, MySQL (and you) would get confused because there would be an ambiguity between employee information referenced from the table on the left side of the join and manager information referenced from the table on the right side of the join. See here for more information about JOINS: [SQL JOINS](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/joins.php)

Comment: what can we asume A and B. Would you please show me how to fetch the records and get values.

Comment: @Gopi6233, not sure that I understand your question, but to clarify: A and B are "table aliases" required to join the employees table to itself. A represents the employees table on the "left" side of the join, and B represents the same employees table on the "right" side of the join. Hope that helps!

Comment: yes, i again executed it by correcting my syntax. I got right answer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `JOIN` the table with itself:

```
SELECT 
    t.emp_id, 
    t.emp_name, 
    t1.emp_name as manager_name 
FROM 
    table1 t 
    LEFT JOIN table1 t1 ON 
        (t.manager_id = t1.emp_id);
```

This will show all employees with their manager. I use `LEFT JOIN` to show also employees without manager.

**EDIT:** (base on PO comment in my answer)

I ment this:

```
SELECT 
    E.emp_id, 
    E.emp_name, 
    M.emp_name as manager_name 
FROM 
    emp_tab as E 
    LEFT JOIN emp_tab as M
ON 
    (E.manager_id = M.emp_id);
```

You have 2 times `emp_tab` - fisrt to get data about employees, second to get data for manager. Because table is presented twice you need alias on each. I use `E` (from employee) and `M` (from manager).

At the top I show employee `name` and `id` and manager `name` (it must be get from the second appearance of the table - `M`).

In the from I am joining tables base on employee manager id from employee table (`E`) with manager id from manager table (`M`).

I use `LEFT JOIN` to show employees which does not have manager. You can replace it with `INNER JOIN` if you need to show only employees with manager.

Comment: Do you mean something like this "SELECT emp_tab.emp_id, emp_tab.emp_name, emp_tab.emp_name as emp_tab.manager_name FROM emp_tab LEFT JOIN emp_tab ON (emp_tab.manager_id = emp_tab.emp_id)", iam even not  getting like this

Comment: Your `SQL` is not correct, @Gopi6233. I updates my answer.

Comment: you ans is right. but iam getting ans if i use like this "SELECT emp_tab.emp_id, emp_tab.emp_name, mgn_tab.emp_name as manager_name FROM emp_tab as emp_tab LEFT JOIN emp_tab as mgn_tab ON (emp_tab.manager_id = mgn_tab.emp_id)" insted of E & M.                                                                                                              Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to use inner join for this purpose.

```
SELECT  e.first_name AS employee,  m.first_name AS manager  
FROM team e  
INNER JOIN team m ON e.manager_id = m.id;
```